# Masking in footage something that comes into view and leaves

Tags: video, tracking, masking

I have footage where the camera pans and e.g. a carpet rod comes into view and then leaves the view. I want to create a mask to later remove the rod with e.g. inpaint.

Objects which are there for all the time of the footage can be tracked, then (if necessary) tracks are averaged and mask can be parented to a track.

This wouldn't work here because no point of the carpet rod is permanently visible (therefore also average track would produce nonsense), so I can't parent the mask to a single track and I haven't seen a way to change the parenting over time.

Is there any other way than moving the mask by hand using keyframes?

Comment: If the carpet rod isn't visible for long enough to even be fully visible and tracked for more than one frame in a row then is it really that big of a deal to just manually keyframe it?

Comment: @Jakemoyo It is fully visible for some time and parts of it are visible for a longer time (but different parts at different times so I can't use a single track as parent).

Comment: Maybe track it in like 3 separate chunks depending on what part is visible, duplicate the mask that number of times and parent each one to it's respective tracker?